# Is there a better way to extract name-value using group() in Matcher?

Tags: java

While extracting named data from input strings, one uses Matcher.group(String groupname)
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

In the code below, receivedData is a hashmap that has the names of the groups. I have to iterate through it to get each name, and then call group(name).
The hashmap has to be maintained separately and can potentially, names can be entered incorrectly or get out of sync with the names in the regex, since there are a large number of them.

```
String patternOfData = "On (day) I ate (mealName) at (restaurant) where they had a deal (entree) for only (price)";
```

After compiling the Pattern,

```
Pattern dataExtractionPattern = Pattern.compile(patternOfData);

Matcher matcher = dataExtractionPattern.matcher(receivedDataString);
                boolean b = matcher.matches();
                if (!b) {
                    return false;
                }
                for (String key : receivedData.keySet()) {
                    String dataValue;
                    dataValue = matcher.group(key);
                    receivedData.put(key, dataValue);
                }
                return true;
```

Wouldnt it be better if we had both name and value being returned together? Like Map.entry group();

Or is there another way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a named capturing group, newly available in Java 7, looks like (?< *NAME* > *PATTERN* ), where *NAME* is the name of the group and *PATTERN* is the pattern to match. So your example regex would be like `On (?<day>\S+) I ate (?<mealName>\S+)...`

If the pattern is fixed, then there is no reason you couldn't have a fixed list of group names. Then you could just build `receivedData` from scratch iterating through those group names, instead of needing it to already be set up with the correct keys.

Comment: The docs are not clear about named-capturing group. "Groups beginning with (? are either pure, non-capturing groups that do not capture text and do not count towards the group total, or named-capturing group." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname

Comment: See [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/named_capturing_group_in_jdk7).

Comment: Javadocs for Pattern "(?<name>X) .....X, as a named-capturing group". Ok, I understand why you put a "\S" to capture non whitespace character